# how to sort mysql data and find position?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have mysql data of 3 rows (user_id, exam_id, marks). 
I want to find each user ranking position based on marks and exam_id .
How will be the SQL query with php code for this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is partial code

```
$p = "SELECT * FROM IDTABLE WHERE EID = '$info[EID]'";
$rowp = mysqli_query($conn, $p);
while (($ret = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowp)) > 0) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM INFOTABLE WHERE EID = '$ret[EID]'";
    $rowq = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
    while (($retq = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowq)) > 0) {                                
        $user[$ret['EID'] . $retq['UID']] = $retq['Marks'];                                
    }
}
arsort($user);
var_dump($user);
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: Please, I need the answer urgently.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: You dont even tell us if you are using `mysqli_` or `PDO`. The idea of SO is that you try and write your oen code and if you have issues with that code you ask for help here.

Comment: Thanks, I use mysqli. Here is partial code. https://pastebin.com/DXX0ZDGx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should consider a few things:

- You should always better search for an already answered question before posting a new one (it's part of stack overflow's code)
- Bring more information of what you want, being as clear as possible
- Giving more details (for example: you sql structure)

However, I will try to give you a hint - Hope it helps!

- For example you want to order your user_id based on their marks:

  select user_id from my_table order by "marks" asc;
- For example you want to order your user_id based on their marks and exam_id :

  select user_id from my_table order by "marks", "exam_id" asc;
- For example you want to create a kind of ranking based on users's marks:

  SET @rank := 0;
  SELECT
      *,
      @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
  FROM my_table
  order by marks ASC;
- For example you want to get the ranking number from a specific

  SET @rank := 0;
  SELECT * from ( select
      *,
      @rank := @rank + 1 
  FROM my_table 
  order by marks ASC ) AS rank where user_id = 2;

Hope this helps! You could get more information about mysql's ranking [here](https://mattmazur.com/2017/03/26/exploring-ranking-techniques-in-mysql/)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. Already I solve the problem myself.

Comment: I have used php associative array.

Comment: Great AL MaMun! I think that phparray could be a good idea, you could also do something like this using what I provided before. You may try both of them and check which one has more perf

    function getRank($user_id, $exam_id, $limit=50) {
    $sql = "
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank, user_id, exam_id, marks
FROM my_table, (SELECT @rank:=1) AS i
ORDER BY `marks` ASC
LIMIT 0, $limit
";

    $result =  mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['user_id'] == $user_id) {
            return $row['Rank'];
        }
    }

    return -1;
}